# Running a package from a cloned repository in GitHub Desktop

Tags: github, conda, virtualenv, environment, github-desktop

I have conda and **GitHub Desktop** installed in my PC, and would like to **fork an existing repository** (Python package) from GitHub, clone it with GitHub desktop to my own PC and work on it (developing and running) in a **local env** (where its dependencies relies), being able of **update all the commits** in the online repository.

How can I achieve this? I have tried to locate the cloned repository in env's site-packages folder but, since the code its within a subfolder (same package name) there are conflicts with the other repository files, such as readme or setup.

Any help or idea would be completely welcome. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a local copy of the repository into a working directory - *not in the environment*. Then with the environment activated, install the local copy of the package with

```
pip install -e pkg_dir
```

Work with it like normal - it is symlinked into the environment.

Generally, one should never need to enter into or edit files in a Conda environment - it tends to lead to trouble, or at least unreproducible states.